# Not able to view Jframe side in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

my code is in netbeans 8.0.2
I tried almost everything, but no results.Please help me out.
**How to show up this in netbeans ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just click on source package (Source files) and it will show your project files.
[image]

Comment: yes but i want the panel info which is shown below . blue marked

Comment: You can just use "CRT + 7" or you can go to Netbeans tab Window and click on it and see all the options and u can find the useful options.